# Reusing exception handling code in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have these two functions, with duplicated exception treatment, which has the sole purpose of displaying an error message:

```
void func1() noexcept {
  try {
    do_task();
    do_another_task();
  } catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    show_msg("Out of range error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::logic_error& e) {
    show_msg("Logic error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::system_error& e) {
    show_msg("System error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
    show_msg("Runtime error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    show_msg("Generic error", e.what());
  }
}

void func2() noexcept {
  try {
    do_something();
    do_something_else();
    do_even_more();
  } catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    show_msg("Out of range error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::logic_error& e) {
    show_msg("Logic error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::system_error& e) {
    show_msg("System error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
    show_msg("Runtime error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    show_msg("Generic error", e.what());
  }
}
```

I could just handle `std::exception` and show a single generic message, but I want to be more specific, that's why I'm catching all possible exceptions.

I want to reuse this exception treatment code. I thought about this:

```
void run_treated(std::function<void()> func) noexcept {
  try {
    func();
  } catch // ... all the catches go here
}

void func1() noexcept {
  run_treated([]()->void {
    do_task();
    do_another_task();
  });
}

void func2() noexcept {
  do_something();
  do_something_else();
  do_even_more();
}
```

1. Is this a good approach?
2. If so, `run_treated` will be called *a lot*. Should I be concerned about performance?
3. Any other approaches?

Comment: At the very least, you should re-throw the exception - otherwise your program is almost certainly in an invalid state.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, consider `func1` and `func2` being at the base of the stack, right after `main`. There's nowhere to go.

Comment: I recommend removing all the `noexcept` tags.

Comment: Then why not do the catching and error reporting once, in main, rather than duplicating it?

Comment: @Eljay, why so?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, I'd love to do that, but it's Windows code with a message pump involved. The best I could do was to reduce it to two possible paths.

Comment: @Rodrigo • because if an exception is thrown from an inner block (say, within the context of func2) of a non-throwing function, then std::terminate will be called.  Which means run_treated won't get a chance to handle the exception.

Comment: @Eljay Why would that be? `std::terminate` is only called if an exception *leaves* a non-throwing function, not when it's *thrown* inside it.

Comment: @Angew • func2 is marked nothrow.  func2 is passed in as a parameter to run_treated.  Presumably, an exception can be thrown inside func2, which would have been handled by run_treated.  But since func2 is marked nothrow, std::terminate will be called instead.

Comment: @Eljay Where is `func2` passed to `run_treated`? The way I see it, `func2` would be implemented the same way as `func1` - by passing a *lambda doing all the work* to `run_treated`. IOW, `run_treated` is an implementation detail of both `func1` and `func2`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's the option of using a [Lippincott Function](http://cppsecrets.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/using-lippincott-function-for.html) to centralize the exception handling logic. Consider this:

```
void Lippincott () noexcept {
  try {
    throw;
  } catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    show_msg("Out of range error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::logic_error& e) {
    show_msg("Logic error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::system_error& e) {
    show_msg("System error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
    show_msg("Runtime error", e.what());
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    show_msg("Generic error", e.what());
  }
}

void func1() noexcept {
  try {
    do_task();
    do_another_task();
  } catch (...) {
    Lippincott();
  }
}

void func2() noexcept {
  try {
    do_something();
    do_something_else();
    do_even_more();
  } catch (...) {
    Lippincott();
  }
}
```

How does it work? When you enter the handler in `func1` or `func2` there is a "current exception" being processed. The body of `Lippincott` starts a new try..catch block and re-throws it. Then it catches the appropriate exceptions and handles them accordingly in a centralized manner.

You should also note that your exception handling logic isn't *really* `noexcept`. There could theoretically be exceptions not covered by your list. In which case there are several places for `std::terminate` to be called, depending on how  you mark things `noexcept`

Comment: This honestly looks more convoluted/cryptic compared to an higher-order function.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - One persons higher-order function is another persons convoluted/cryptic. I don't deny the approaches are *vastly* different.

Comment: This doesn't look more convoluted to me. Pretty straightforward and clean. It has the added benefit that you don't need to expose the exception handling code through a header (although you could add another layer to work around this).

Comment: @OnMyLittleDuck: you don't need to expose the handling code through an header. You can use lightweight type erasure (e.g. `function_ref`: https://vittorioromeo.info/Misc/p0792r1.html).

Comment: BTW, this looks more convoluted to me for multiple reasons: more boilerplate (every function that wants to use the exception handling logic must be wrapped in a `try`-`catch` itself, where the `catch` is a function call to `Lippincott`); and we need a `try { throw; }`. I believe that using an higher-order function simply allows you to provide a customization point for "an arbitrary block of code" already wrapped in a single `try...catch` - that's why I find it more straightforward.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - Your prerogative. Though depending on how much the logic is shared, a template may very well increase build times. YMMV, of course. Anybody is welcome to prefer whatever solution they like, and whatever hammer makes them see nails all over the place.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Type-erasing the callable means that you pay the type erasure cost all the time, every time. The cost here is only paid on the exceptional code path.

Comment: Nice trick! Now only wonder why is it called "Lippencott" function. There is no online source that tells us the origin...

Comment: @Calmarius - It's named after Lisa Lippincott. You can find her talks from cppcon and boostcon on youtube. She doesn't discuss this in any of them, but I heard attribution being given to her for the trick, so I keep it :)

Answer (score 14):

> Is this a good approach?

Yes. It prevents code duplication and allows you to easily customize behavior by passing in a lambda.

---

> If so, `run_treated` will be called a lot. Should I be concerned about performance?

Yes. `std::function` is **not** a zero-cost abstraction. You should use a *template parameter* to pass the lambda without requiring type erasure.

```
template <typename F>
void run_treated(F&& func) noexcept {
  try {
    std::forward<F>(func)();
  } catch // ... all the catches go here
}
```

I discuss and benchmark various techniques to pass functions to other functions in this article: [**"passing functions to functions"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html).

If you don't want to use a template to pass `func`, you can use something like `function_ref` *(proposed for standardization [P0792](https://vittorioromeo.info/Misc/p0792r1.html))*. An implementation is available here: [`function_ref.cpp`](https://github.com/SuperV1234/Experiments/blob/master/function_ref.cpp).

---

Unrelated comments:

- Those unconditional `noexcept` specifiers look fishy. Can you actually guarantee that no exception will ever escape those functions?
- `[]()->void {}` is equivalent to `[]{}`.

Comment: If an exception like "`std::function` crash" happens, there's nothing I can do other than end the program, so let the program call `std::terminate`, by itself. Other than that, I guarantee no other exceptions will be thrown.

Comment: I'm aware of the `[]{}`, I just like to be explicit in reused codebases of mine.

Comment: If construction of the `std::function` throws an exception, it happens in the context of the caller, not the noexcept callee.

Comment: Since `func` has no arguments, is `std::forward` necessary? See [code here](https://pastebin.com/bgpyhJnS).