# A function that trys its argument function - Would that even be a good idea?

Tags: c++, function, try-catch

Consider the following (not working) code:

```
#include <iostream>

void tried_function()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world";
}

void try_function (std::function function_to_try)
{
    try
    {
        function_to_try();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //handle failed try here
    }
}

int main()
{
    try_function(tried_function);
    return 0;
}
```

Desired output:

```
Hello world!
or errorhandling
```

You could expand the try-block to catch the most common exceptions and instead of writing a few try-blocks for all sorts of stuff you could just use the `try_function` and save a few keystrokes.

But would that be a good idea or do I overlook something?

Comment: A good idea for what? In general you don't want to just catch exceptions, output something and go on as if nothing happened. Usually you want to change the behavior of the rest of the code if an exception happens, e.g. you might need to retry the earlier action that failed or you might need to end the program gracefully, etc. The question as is seems too vague to me. If you are asking how to achieve that behavior, your code is almost there. You just need to replace `std::function` with `std::function<void()>` and `#include<functional>`.

Comment: @walnut ah, so it's not always clear cut what the error handling looks like, and therefore making one function to try them all is impossible?

Comment: If you are asking about reusing exception handling logic, it has been asked before, for instace [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036435/reusing-exception-handling-code-in-c). If you are asking about your *specific* approach, then please make that explicit. Your question is a bit vague.