# How to simplify the repetitive exception handling in C++

Tags: c++, exception, refactoring

I have a following pattern that repeats with the custom exception handling:

```
#include <exception>

struct E_1 : std::exception {};
struct E_2 : std::exception {};
struct E_3 : std::exception {};
// ...
// struct E_n {};

void handle(const E_1&) { /* E_1 handling */ }
void handle(const E_2&) { /* E_2 handling */ }
void handle(const E_3&) { /* E_3 handling */ }
// ...
// void handle(const E_n&) { /* E_n handling */ }

int main()
{
    try { /* Something that may throw E_n */ }
    catch(const E_1& e) { handle(e); }
    catch(const E_2& e) { handle(e); }
    catch(const E_3& e) { handle(e); }
    // ...
    // catch(const E_n& e) { handle(e); }
}
```

Here I have multiple overloads of `void handle(...)` and each of them deals in a certain way with the specific exception. The repetitive part is that, on each catch of the exception, the handling is the same by calling the `handle` function. Is there a more elegant way to deal with this?

Comment: It should be possible to have all exception classes inherit from a common base class, catch the base class, and use a virtual `handle()` to implement the exception handling.

Comment: You could have a `common_handler()` function that does all the common handling stuff, and have each `handle` call the `common_handler()`.

Comment: This has the look of overusing exceptions.

Comment: You can collapse the handlers into one if you need to https://stackoverflow.com/q/48036435/817643 - I find it useful as a way to convert exceptions to error codes on an ABI boundary.

Comment: what is `E_1` and `E_2` and `E_3` actually? Why do they not inherit from `std::exception` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I left that out for simplicity, just added it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is with polymorphism.
one option is:

```
#include <exception>

class ExceptionInterface : std::exception {
public:
    virtual void handle() {};
};

class E_1 : std::exception {
public:
    void handle() { };
};
class E_2 : std::exception {
public:
    void handle() { };
};
class E_3 : std::exception {
public:
    void handle() { };
};


int main()
{
    try {/* code*/}
    catch (ExceptionInterface *e)
    {
        // the compiler call the exception according the type
        e->handle();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you can change it to *const*, and the function need to be also *const*.